# How to display an alert box using Alarm Manager and BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog, android-broadcast, android-alarms

I want my android app to pop-up an alert dialog box at specific time of each day. Of what I have understood is that we need to use Alarm manager to set the time of the day on repeating, and then send a broadcast to display the alert dialog box. The alert box should be displayed at the specified time even if the app is closed. I have tried the following code but it does not do anything at the specified time. Please suggest what needs to be done. I am new to android development and this is my very first implementation.

Main_Activity

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,Calendar.MONTH,Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,6, 10);
    setAlarm(calendar.getTimeInMillis());


}

private void setAlarm(long timeInMillis) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertBox.class);

    PendingIntent penIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,timeInMillis,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,penIntent);

    //Toast.makeText(this,"Alarm is set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

AlertBox

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   DisplayAlertBox(context, "Tip of the Day");
}

private void DisplayAlertBox(Context context, String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Dialog Box should display Now", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    PendingIntent alertBox = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0, new Intent(context,MainActivity.class),0);

    AlertDialog.Builder aBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    aBuilder.setTitle("Message");
    aBuilder.setMessage(msg);
    aBuilder.setPositiveButton("Accept",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int whichButton)
        {

        }});

    aBuilder.create();
    aBuilder.show();
}
```

Comment: maybe show it when the user goes into the app each day. that would be easier if you use services to check a shared pref. if user goes into the app, oncreate check the shared pref. if false, show alert.

Comment: @DroiDev The task aims at providing workout routine tips to patients. Even if they don't use the app, they should get the tips in alert dialog box at the specific time of the day. This is just like a reminder notification, but instead of the notification I want the reminder to go as an alert dialog box.

Comment: @user1717876 If this tips are really that important I'd use a Service running in it's own process to fire the notifications, instead of an IntentService. You are going to have better control, you are going to have all the business logic related to when to fire the notifications in one single place and you will have less boilerplate code in your UI.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why nothing is happening is because you don't have a clear understanding of BroadcastReceiver.

BroadcastReceivers, once registered, will sit there waiting for a broadcast that it can receive. Registering a BroadcastReceiver can be done in both your Manifest file or through your code. The broadcast that it can wait to receive can be either an implicit or explicit broadcast. But in your case, it's an explicit broadcast. So you would declare it in your Manifest like so:

```
<receiver android:name="com.package.AlertBox">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="can.be.any.name.like.tip.of.the.day"
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

You may also register the BroadcastReceiver through code if you don't want to do so through the Manifest.

Your problem is that the intent that you're sending to your AlarmManager is **Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertBox.class)**. What this does is that it's only going to start your BroadcastReceiver, which isn't necessary once it's already registered. It's onReceive() is never called this way.

Your AlertBox will only show the AlertDialog when onReceive() is called, but onReceive is never called because a BroadcastReceiver's onReceive is only called when it receives the broadcast it's registered to receive.

So your setAlarm() method should be written like this:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent("can.be.any.name.like.tip.of.the.day");
PendingIntent penIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, penIntent);
```

Keep in mind that the String that's used as the action of the Intent must match the String that your Broadcast Receiver is listening to. This way, the onReceive() method will be able to trigger.

However, I should also mention that the BroadcastReceiver **should not** be where you run your AlertDialog. BroadcastReceivers are meant for short execution of codes and are not meant to persist for a lengthy amount of time. For that, an Activity or Service would be a better option.

You should consider having the AlarmManager launch a transparent Activity that hosts a DialogFragment instead.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. Regarding your last suggestion of using an Activity instead of BroadcastReceiver, will it work even when the app is closed. I want the dialog box to appear even when the app is not in use. This was the reason I was using BroadcastReceiver. Or Should I create a Service?

Comment: @user1717876 It doesn't matter if you're using Activity, BroadcastReceiver, or Service when you're using the AlarmManager. If you look at AlarmManager's documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager you'll notice the 3rd sentence saying your application will be started if it's not running. So even if you use Activity and your app is closed, AlarmManager will start your app and show the Activity that you have set in the Intent provided to the AlarmManager. I recommend using a Activity because BroadcastReceivers and Services are not meant for displaying Dialogs.